# Class is not being added with if statement

Tags: jquery

I have three navigations and I only want the display the one that has the active class, but i'm not able to achieve this. As you can see the list item is the element that has the active class so i'm targeting the list items and not the ul. Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('.book ul li').hasClass('active')){
        $(this).addClass('showActiveBook');
    }
});
```

```css
.book{
    display: none;
}
.showActiveBook{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="book book1">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Book1</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="book book2">
  <ul>
     <a href="#">Book 2</a>
     <li class="active"> 
         <ul>
             <li>book2Chapter1</li>
             <li>book2Chapter2</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="book book3">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Book3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `this` is incorrect.  Without proper chaining, the `this` will reference the document or window.  However, in your case you do not need an if statement.  Simply find the li that has the class of active, find it's parent book element, and add the class to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.book ul li.active').closest('.book').addClass('showActiveBook');
});
```

```css
.book{
    display: none;
}
.showActiveBook{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="book book1">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Book1</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="book book2">
  <ul>
     <a href="#">Book 2</a>
     <li class="active"> 
         <ul>
             <li>book2Chapter1</li>
             <li>book2Chapter2</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="book book3">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Book3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the `'li.active'` instead of getting all of them and testing, and you can use `parents(2)` to get the second parent (the parent `nav` element):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.book ul li.active').parents(2).addClass('showActiveBook');
});
```

```css
.book{
    display: none;
}
.showActiveBook{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="book book1">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Book1</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="book book2">
  <ul>
     <a href="#">Book 2</a>
     <li class="active"> 
         <ul>
             <li>book2Chapter1</li>
             <li>book2Chapter2</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="book book3">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <a href="#">Book3</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```